# Incoming GSM Call Receive in Android and Make confererence to a SIP Number

Tags: gsm, phone-call

I am new in Android Development. Can you show me some way How to at Android:

1) Receive Incoming GSM Call and Auto answer
2) Connect/make call to  my Sip Account (Asterisk Server Installed my home)
3) Make the Conference.

That mean Any Incoming GSM call need to forward to SIP Conference. Please show me some path from where I can Start?

Answer (score 0):

Start with auto answering:
[http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Feverysoft%2Fautoanswer](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse#svn/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer)
Then go to the other part.